# Why web3.db.putString throws error?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, storage, leveldb

Whenever i try `web3.db.putString("user","name","jon_lobo")` command from Geth console it throwsbelow error

> Error: The method db_putString does not exist/is not available
>       at web3.js:3119:20
>       at web3.js:6023:15
>       at web3.js:4995:36
>       at :1:1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the web3.db had been removed in geth 1.4, I personally met the same problem before

```
> web3.db
{
  getHex: function(),
  getString: function(),
  putHex: function(),
  putString: function()
}
> web3.db.putString('testDB', 'key', 'myString')
Error: The method db_putString does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> web3.db.putHex('testDB', 'key', web3.fromAscii('myString'))
Error: The method db_putHex does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> web3.db.getString('testDB', 'key')
Error: The method db_getString does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> web3.db.getHex('testDB', 'key')
Error: The method db_getHex does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3104:20
    at web3.js:6191:15
    at web3.js:5004:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> web3.version
{
  api: "0.18.1",
  ethereum: "0x3f",
  network: "65535",
  node: "Geth/v1.6.1-stable-021c3c28/linux-amd64/go1.8.1",
  whisper: undefined,
  getEthereum: function(callback),
  getNetwork: function(callback),
  getNode: function(callback),
  getWhisper: function(callback)
}
```

and I found this answer: [Remove web3.db](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/311),

---

hope it could help